# Merge sort struct by last name giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

I'm trying to sort an array of structs by last name, if it's the same last name, then by first name.

```
struct Person {
    std::string kNum;
    std::string last;
    std::string first;
    int zipCode;
};
```

These are the functions for the merge sort.

```
void nameSort(Person* array, int size) {
    int high = size - 1;
    mergeSort(array, 0, high);
}
```

```
void mergeSort(Person* arr, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int mid = low + (high - 1) / 2;

        mergeSort(arr, low, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, high);

        merge(arr, low, mid, high);
    }
}
```

```
void merge(Person* arr, int low, int mid, int high) {
    Person *temp = new Person[high - low + 1];
    int i = low;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k =0;

    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (arr[i].last != arr[j].last) {
            if (arr[i].last <= arr[j].last) {
                temp[k++] = arr[j++];
            } else {
                temp[k++] = arr[i++];
            }
        } else {
            if (arr[i].first <= arr[j].last) {
                temp[k++] = arr[j++];
            } else {
                temp[k++] = arr[i++];
            }
        }
    }

    while (i < mid) {
        temp[k++] = arr[i++];
    }
    while(j <= high) {
        temp[k++] = arr[j++];
    }

    for (int x = low; x < high; ++x) {
        arr[x] = temp[x];
    }


    delete [] temp;
}
```

On the console is just exits. I ran it on DrMemory and is giving me a segmentation fault. I tried to look for where it went out of bounds but can't find it.

Comment: If the console version exits normally, have you tried to output the result array to see if it's correct?

Comment: Yes, on main I have the nameSort and the print function.

Comment: Start by adding `bool operator<(const Person& rhs) const {
        if(last == rhs.last)
            return first < rhs.first;
        else
            return last < rhs.last;
    }` to your `Person` struct. It should make the rest easier to handle.

Comment: There's an indexing problem in your result-copying loop (think about the bounds of `temp`), and there's a typo in the merge loop.

Comment: i think mid = low + (high-low)/2

Comment: Is this really correct: `if (arr[i].first <= arr[j].last)` ? It seems incorrect. That'd be easier to spot if you'd put the comparison function in the `Person` struct itself.

Comment: @ZexianLi *I tried to look for where it went out of bounds but can't find it.* -- If you had used `std::vector<Person>` instead of `new []` and regular arrays/pointers, it would have been very simple to detect an out-of-bounds condition by simply using `at()` when accessing your items instead of `[ ]` and then let the system automatically tell you that you've gone out of bounds.

Comment: I think part of the problem is in mid now I'm that printing it. mid is just repeating itself after some steps into the function.

Comment: To be clearer than my previous comment: you're indexing `temp` from `low` to `high-1`, but its valid indexes are from `0` to `high -low`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for pointing that typo. I have another project where I have two Person structs(not array) and an empty temp, then I compare them with the if statements and set ```temp``` equal to the bigger one and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: @ZexianLi -- 1) Give us a sample of the data that shows the issue.  2) Do not compare what you did in other projects to the code you have now.  That other project is a different program, different code, different code flow, different variables, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm using [link](http://faculty.chemeketa.edu/ascholer/cs260/Assignments/Assign01/people.txt) and I'm reading in the first 10 persons. And I'm printing `low, mid, high` and they output this [link](https://gyazo.com/d30a3fc21fd5695835bded7c6145ecb8)

Comment: You really should be testing your code with 2 or 3 items, not 10, 20, or 100.  If you can't sort 3, you aren't going to be able to sort 10 (or hundreds).

Comment: There are a couple of things that would be correct if you were working with traditional half-open intervals, but are wrong now.

Comment: @molbdnilo could you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @ZexianLi you have one error in _mergeSort_ and two in _merge_, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having

> ```
>  void mergeSort(Person* arr, int low, int high) {
>    if (low < high) {
>        int mid = low + (high - 1) / 2;
>
>        mergeSort(arr, low, mid);
> ```

you have a first problem about *mid*, for instance if *low* is 2 and *high* is 3 then *mid* values 3 and you call *mergeSort* again with *low* is 2 and *high* is 3 recursively up to explode the stack.

Visibly as its name signifies *mid* must be the middle index between *low* and *high* so

```
int mid = (low + high) / 2;
```

Other problems are in *merge*

doing

> ```
>  while (i < mid) {
>    temp[k++] = arr[i++];
>  }
> ```

you miss the element rank *mid*, must be

```
while (i <= mid) {
    temp[k++] = arr[i++];
}
```

doing

> ```
> for (int x = low; x < high; ++x) {
>     arr[x] = temp[x];
> }
> ```

you suppose both *arr* and *temps* have the same size and their index correspond, but this is false, *temp* is a sub part of *arr*, must be

```
for (i = low, k = 0; i <= high; ++i, ++k)
  arr[i] = temp[k];
```

After these changes your program sorts well the elements

---

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Person {
    std::string kNum;
    std::string last;
    std::string first;
    int zipCode;
};

void merge(Person* arr, int low, int mid, int high) {
    Person *temp = new Person[high - low + 1];
    int i = low;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k =0;

    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (arr[i].last != arr[j].last) {
            if (arr[i].last <= arr[j].last) {
                temp[k++] = arr[j++];
            } else {
                temp[k++] = arr[i++];
            }
        } else {
            if (arr[i].first <= arr[j].last) {
                temp[k++] = arr[j++];
            } else {
                temp[k++] = arr[i++];
            }
        }
    }

    while (i <= mid) {
        temp[k++] = arr[i++];
    }
    while(j <= high) {
        temp[k++] = arr[j++];
    }

    for (i = low, k = 0; i <= high; ++i, ++k)
      arr[i] = temp[k];


    delete [] temp;
}

void mergeSort(Person* arr, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2; // mid

        mergeSort(arr, low, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, high);

        merge(arr, low, mid, high);
    }
}

void nameSort(Person* array, int size) {
    int high = size - 1;
    mergeSort(array, 0, high);
}

int main()
{
  Person a[] = {
    { "K1000001","Thompson","Loyal",97894 },
    { "K1000002","Abbott","Ward",97095 },
    { "K1000003","Hauck","Mario",97587 },
    { "K1000004","Mertz","Bret",97070 },
    { "K1000005","Jacobs","Hubert",97364 },
    { "K1000006","Rolfson","Dixie",97335 },
    { "K1000007","Weber","Yoshiko",97091 },
    { "K1000008","Beier","Jessika",97858 },
    { "K1000009","White","Sophie",97719 },
    { "K1000010","Dibbert","Jordyn",97607 },
    { "K1000011","Schultz","Markus",97515 },
    { "K1000012","Kemmer","Bonnie",97264 },
    { "K1000013","Klein","Llewellyn",97699 },
    { "K1000014","Barton","Callie",97276 },
    { "K1000015","Bartell","Erich",97884 },
    { "K1000016","Marks","Annabel",97493 },
    { "K1000017","Hirthe","Mekhi",97487 },
    { "K1000018","Gleichner","Zita",97073 },
  };
  const int sz = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

  for (int i = 0; i != sz; ++i)
    std::cout << a[i].last << ' ' << a[i].first << ' ' << a[i].kNum << ' ' << a[i].zipCode << std::endl;

  std::cout << "---------" << std::endl;

  nameSort(a, sz);

  for (int i = 0; i != sz; ++i)
    std::cout << a[i].last << ' ' << a[i].first << ' ' << a[i].kNum << ' ' << a[i].zipCode << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall s.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Thompson Loyal K1000001 97894
Abbott Ward K1000002 97095
Hauck Mario K1000003 97587
Mertz Bret K1000004 97070
Jacobs Hubert K1000005 97364
Rolfson Dixie K1000006 97335
Weber Yoshiko K1000007 97091
Beier Jessika K1000008 97858
White Sophie K1000009 97719
Dibbert Jordyn K1000010 97607
Schultz Markus K1000011 97515
Kemmer Bonnie K1000012 97264
Klein Llewellyn K1000013 97699
Barton Callie K1000014 97276
Bartell Erich K1000015 97884
Marks Annabel K1000016 97493
Hirthe Mekhi K1000017 97487
Gleichner Zita K1000018 97073
---------
White Sophie K1000009 97719
Weber Yoshiko K1000007 97091
Thompson Loyal K1000001 97894
Schultz Markus K1000011 97515
Rolfson Dixie K1000006 97335
Mertz Bret K1000004 97070
Marks Annabel K1000016 97493
Klein Llewellyn K1000013 97699
Kemmer Bonnie K1000012 97264
Jacobs Hubert K1000005 97364
Hirthe Mekhi K1000017 97487
Hauck Mario K1000003 97587
Gleichner Zita K1000018 97073
Dibbert Jordyn K1000010 97607
Beier Jessika K1000008 97858
Barton Callie K1000014 97276
Bartell Erich K1000015 97884
Abbott Ward K1000002 97095
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. It was fewer errors than what I thought.